# Is MPI communication considered to be part of the parallel part of the program

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I currently have the following MPI program skeleton:

```
init();
for(i=0 to 1000):
   for(j=0 to 1000):
      MPI_Scatter(); /* scatter some data */
      MPI_Bcast(); /* broadcast some data */
      //parallel code
      MPI_Reduce(); /* reduce some data */

//final print
```

I am trying to time to program to see what the speedup is but I am not sure what to consider to be the parallel part - more specifically, should I include the MPI communication (scatter, broadcast, reduce) in the time or should I just time the parallel code?

Update: The time will be used to compute the speedup of the program

Comment: That (obviously) depends on what you are interested in. What is the purpose of timing it? What do you want to compare it to?

Comment: Usually, we are interested in comparing overall execution time, for example if we want to compare to non-parallelized versions or to some other parallelization method. But if you want to compare your nodes amog each other, for example because they use different hardware or settings, you might be interested in the pure calculation time.

Comment: @Hulk, I am trying to compute the Amdahl speedup of my program, so I need to compute the times of the parallel and serial portion of the program so I can get the ratio - that is my end goal.

Comment: For comparison with sequential execution I'd always use overall execution time (including the communication part). Amdahls argument was, if I read it correctly, that some parts of the program (initialization, and some parts of aggregation of results) cannot be parallelized, so excluding these parts from the measurements would be strange.